# Finding a basis for vector space $U$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ denote the subspace of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ defined by

> $$U=\left\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\ c&0\end{matrix}\right):a + b + c=0\right\rbrace.$$

How would one find a basis for that vector space? Any clues please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the only requirement is that $a+b+c=0$, and since we don't require the matrix to be invertible, a general matrix is then
$$\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\ -a-b&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
Can you work out the basis from here?

Comment: So then the basis will be B = {[1 0, -1 0],[0 1, -1 0]}.Did you assume that it's also linearly independent?

Comment: That is the right basis. Also, the fact that they are linearly independent is easy to prove. If you are satisfied with the answer, mark it correct to remove it from the unanswered section.

Comment: Thanks!Out of curiosity, how would you set up the general matrix if the zero in U is replaced with d and the new condition is a + b + c + d = 0?

Comment: Well, the same thing really. First, make one variable dependent on the rest of the variables, so we have $d=-a-b-c$, so work out the general matrix. Then notice that we have 3 "free" variables in $a,b,c$, so the dimension of the basis must be 3. Can you work it out? I'm happy to explain more if you need me to.

Comment: I understand now :)!!! I asked a question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447949/find-the-span-of-the-following-matrix and want to find the basis for that span, will it be B={[-1 0, 0 1]}?

Comment: Yup! It is exactly the same matrix as before; this is really by definition.